# Getting gmake to complete a recipe early

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make, exit, recipe

I know this has been asked before, but none of the solutions I've found work for me because they're anti-DRY.

I have a number of targets that depend on things that can't readily be timestamped -- such as files copied from another system.  What I'd **like** to be able to do is list dependencies in a variable, like `nobuild=this,that`, and have those targets be *assumed* to be up-to-date.  Since I have a lot of these, I *don't* want to `ifdef` around each one; what would be pseudocodibly preferable would be something like

```
ignorable-target: dependencies
        $(call ifnobuild,$@)
        .. rest of normal build steps ..
```

where the `ifnobuild` macro expanded to some sort of *exit-from-this-recipe-with-success* `gmake` instruction if `ignorable-target` was mentioned in the `nobuild` variable.

I also *don't* want to get into multi-line continued shell commands in order to defer the conditional to the recipe itself; I want to be able to tell make "Assume these targets are up-to-date and don't try to build them," so I can test other aspects with the local copies already obtained from the problematic recipes.

There **isn't** any sort of *exit-recipe-with-success* mechanism in `gmake`, is there?

[Edited to hopefully make the situation more clear.]

Here's an example.  Targets `remote1` and `remote2` each involve using `ssh` to do something time-consuming on a remote system, and then copying the results locally.  Target `local1` is built locally, and isn't a time sink.  `target-under-work` depends on all three of the above.

```
local1: local1.c Makefile

remote1: local1
        scp local1 remote-host:/tmp/
        ssh remote-host /tmp/local1 some-args # takes a long time
        scp remote-host:/tmp/local1.out remote1

remote2: local1
        scp local1 other-host:/tmp/
        ssh other-host /tmp/local1 other-args # takes a long time
        scp other-host:/tmp/local1.out remote2

target-under-work: local1 remote1 remote2
        do-something-with remote1,remote2
```

Now, when I just run `make target-under-work`, it's going to run the recipes for `remote1` and `remote2`.  However, the local copies of those files are 'good enough' for my testing, so I *don't* want them run every time.  Once things go into production, they *will* be run every time, but while I'm developing `target-under-work`, I just want to use the copies already built, and I can rebuild them daily (or whatever) for the necessary  testing granularity.

The above is over-simplified; there are multiple steps and targets that depend on `remote1` and/or `remote2`.  I see how I can get the effect I want by making them order-only prerequisites -- but that would mean changing the dependency list of every target that has them as prerequisites, rather than making a *single* change to `remote1` and `remote2` so I can use some variable from the command line to tell their recipes 'pretend this has been built, don't actually build it if there's already a copy.'

I hope this makes my question more clear.

Comment: If a target is never to be rebuilt, why have a rule for it? And are any of these targets prerequisites of anything else?

Comment: Do you know about [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-prerequisites_002c-order_002donly)? I may be wrong but I suspect that they could be what you are looking for.

Comment: It's not that they're never to be rebuilt; they *do* get rebuilt.  But they take a long time, and when I'm working on something that's dependent upon them, I want to use what I have from the last build, not go build it again.  There's no way to timestamp them because there's no way (without doing all the remote work) to tell if anything has changed.

I want to be able to selectively say 'this doesn't need to be rebuilt'; when the pieces are done they'll all be built normally.

Answer (score 1):

No, this early exit make feature does not exist.

Note that your problem is probably under-specified because you don't explain what behaviour you want when a *slow* target does not exist yet.

Let's assume that the slow targets listed in `nobuild` shall be rebuilt if and only if they don't exist. Instead of using make functions to early exit their recipe you could use make functions to "hide" their list of prerequisites. This way, if they already exist, they will not be rebuilt, even if they are outdated. The only subtlety is that you will need the second expansion to use the `$@` automatic variable in the lists of prerequisites. In the following example `slow` (your `remoteX`) depends on `fast1` (your `local1`). `fast2` (your `target-under-work`) depends on `fast1` and `slow`:

```
host> cat Makefile
# Expands as empty string if $(1) exists and
# listed in $(nobuild). Else expands as $(2).
# $(1): target
# $(2): prerequisites
define HIDE_IF_NOBUILD
$(if $(wildcard $(1)),$(if $(filter $(1),$(nobuild)),,$(2)),$(2))
endef

nobuild :=

fast1:
    @echo 'build $@'
    @touch $@

fast2: fast1 slow
    @echo 'build $@'
    @touch $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:

slow: $$(call HIDE_IF_NOBUILD,$$@,fast1)
    @echo 'build $@'
    @touch $@

# Case 1: slow target not listed in nobuild and not existing
host> rm -f slow; touch fast1; make fast2
build slow
build fast2

# Case 2: slow target not listed in nobuild and existing and outdated
host> touch slow; sleep 2; touch fast1; make fast2
build slow
build fast2

# Case 3: slow target listed in nobuild and not existing
host> rm -f slow; touch fast1; make nobuild="slow" fast2
build slow
build fast2

# Case 4: slow target listed in nobuild and existing and outdated
host> touch slow; sleep 2; touch fast1; make nobuild="slow" fast2
build fast2
```

Comment: This makes sense, although it's far more complex than I had hoped, and it required modifying the prereqs of all the *targets* rather than just the recipe for the prereq itself.  I'll play with this a bit.  Thanks!

Comment: @RoUS There must be something I did not understand: I thought what you wanted was modifying the recipes of _ignorable-targets_. What I propose is modifying their list of prerequisites instead of the recipe. And, in the last version, in a way that seems no more complex than your `$(call ifnobuild,$@)` initial proposal. But in your comment you mention the _recipe for the prereq itself_. What did I miss here?

Comment: If five different targets depend on the long-running prereq, each of their recipes need to be updated.  If your example, it's `depend1` and `depend2` that i want to list in `nobuild`, because those dependencies are the ones that are time-intensive and difficult to timestamp.

Any better?

Comment: @RoUS: So, if `depend1` and `depend2` are listed in `nobuild` you want to avoid re-building `target`? Easy enough but underspecified: what if only `depend1` is listed and not `depend2`?

Comment: No, if `depend1` is in `nobuild`, I want it treated as though as it has been built and `target` to proceed as though `depend1` *had* been built.  This is getting confusing; let me rework the original question text.

Comment: @RoUS: What I did not make clear enough in my previous answers is that it is the prerequisites of your `remote1`  and `remote2` that you can hide or turn into order-only prerequisites. This way, if `remote1`  and `remote2` already exist, they will not be redone. Leave the other rules as they are. I'll edit my answer once more to make it 100% clear.